# MongoDB host replacement causes java application authenticationexception

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver

We are using mongodb-driver-core 4.2.3 & mongo db 4.2.

Authentication is done using Kerberos

When one of the MongoDB host was replaced in datacenter, it caused below error message

"Authentication Failed on Server XYZ" Code: 18
(mechanism GSSAPI)

We have 8 service instances and found this issue on 3 instances only.

Unfortunately, I won't be able to provide the full stack trace here.